# Functions and Linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline f(x)&x\\\hline2&-3\\\hline0&0\\\hline a+5&b\\\hline\end{array}$$

decide whether $1$ or $2$ or both of the information given is enough to solve for $3a+2b$

$1. f (x) = mx + c$

$2. f(6) = 4$

What I think the answer is, is that both the information given are not enough, because we don't know the gradient of the equation. Is my answer correct? Or can we find the gradient from the information given? I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Code for the table: `\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline f(x)&x\\\hline2&-3\\\hline0&0\\\hline a+5&b\\\hline\end{array}`. `|c|c|` stands for three vertical lines and two columns. '\hline` means horizontal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can begin by concluding that $(2)$ by itself is rather useless since it does not give us any information about the functions general behaviour, just the specific value at $x=6$.

$(1)$ is however quite strong on its own. Since we know that $f(0)=0$, we can quickly see that $c=0$, and thus $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x)=mx$. The constant $m$ can be solved for using $f(-3)=2$ to give:
$$2=-3m\iff m=-\frac{2}{3}.$$
Now we know that $f(x)=-\frac{2x}{3}$, and we have one relation, namely $f(b)=a+5$, left. At first glance it may  not seem solvable since we have two unknowns $a$ and $b$, but watch what happens if we plug $f(b)=a+5$ into our function:
$$a+5=-\frac{2b}{3}\iff 3a+15=-2b\iff3a+2b=-15.$$
We can thus conclude that we can answer the question with the help of $(1)$ alone. Also note that $(2)$ is contradictory, since $f(6)=-\frac{2\cdot 6}{3}=-4$, not $4$. Is there perhaps a typo in the question?

Comment: thanks that helped me a lot!

Comment: yes, there is a typo. it was -4

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem properly, I think if you were given Information $1$ then you should be able to solve $3a+2b$. However, if you were given both $1$ and $2$ then you will not be able to solve it.

Say you were given $(1)$ then you immediately know the gradient is $\frac{-2}{3}$ whilst the intercept is $0$. However, this will has a contradiction if $(2)$ has to be satisfied, too.

If we assume the gradient is given as above, we have that $f(b)=\frac{-2}{3}b=a+5$. Simple arrangement will give you the desired answer.

Comment: thanks too, just wandering!